# PHP Login form need to be submited 2x

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have got problem, that I can't figure out. All of my other forms work correctly. But Login Form, need to be completed 2 times, before it executes.

I need to input username and password, submit form, and page refreshes.
When I input username/password and submit second time, function works and goes to profile.php

Login.php

```
    <?php
    require_once("../Style/user-navigation.php");
    require_once("../System/class.user.php");

    $user = new USER();

    if($user->is_loggedin()!=""){
    ?><script> location.replace("Home.php?action=select&id=<?php echo $userRow['id']; ?>"); </script>
    <?php   
    }

    if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])){
        $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
        $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

        if($user->doLogin($username,$password)){ ?>
        <script> location.replace("Home.php?action=select&id=<?php echo $userRow['id']; ?>"); </script>
        <?php
        }
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body class="nav-md" style="background-image: url('https://zellox.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/background-website-%E2%80%AB1%E2%80%AC-1600x900.gif');">

        <!-- page content -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <a class="hiddenanchor" id="signin"></a>

        <div class="login_wrapper">
        <div class="animate form login_form">
          <section class="login_content">
            <form method="post">
              <h1>Login Form</h1>
              <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="" />
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="" />
              </div>
              <div>
               <button type="submit" name="btn-login" class="btn btn-primary ">Log In</button>
                <a class="reset_pass" href="#">Lost your password?</a>
              </div>

              <div class="clearfix"></div>

              <div class="separator">
                <p class="change_link">New to site?
                  <a href="Register.php" class="to_register"> Create Account </a>
                </p>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <br />

              </div>
            </form>
          </section>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <!-- /page content -->
  </body>
</html>
```

And backend code "class.user.php" Login function

```
public function doLogin($username,$password){
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username=:username");
            $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                if($password= $userRow['password'])
                {                   
                    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['id'];
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your (js) redirect, you have `<?php echo $userRow['id']; ?>`. Surley `$userRow['id']` isn't set until the user is logged in, right? I can't see you setting that variable after you do the actual login. (well, I can't see you actually setting that variable _anywhere_.

Comment: `if($password= $userRow['password'])` <-- you're setting the variable, not comparing. You need `==` or `===` to compare.

Comment: _Never store passwords in clear text!_. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson True my own grammar mistakes..  big thanks. Somehow didn't see that. Please, make it as answer and I will check it. :)

Comment: `$userRow['id']` is defined inside a method and is therefor only accessible inside that method. Look into scopes.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I store them as hash when register. :) $new_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

Comment: If it's stored as a hash (using password_hash()), you must use `password_verify()` to validate the password. Simply comparing them with `==` won't work. `password_hash()` will give you a different hash every time. And you really shouldn't escape or strip passwords before they are hashed. That actually changes the passwords and can weaken them.

Answer (score 0):

Add it before using sessions and HTML:

session_start();